# how to reduce multiple categorical predictors with large number of categories for classification?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

The dataset contains a few categorical variables with many categories(approx 10000 categories) in an ADs dataset.
The objective is to predict if ad will be clicked or not?
Could anyone suggest how to reduce these variable.

a few variables i have removed as they were nearzero variance predictors.

Comment: When I do this type of ad analysis, I sometimes have to review the categories manually in order to look for groups that are very similar. It's annoying to do but sometimes it's the best way.

Comment: I guess when you ask "how" to reduce you mean what philosophy to use, rather than how the code should look like, right? One easy way, but not always the best, is to reduce based on popularity. Like counting how many times you have each category for your variable X. You might have a few categories with many counts and lots of them with 1-20 counts. Maybe you want to group all those together as "rare" or "non popular" or "rest".

Comment: @AntoniosK. same, I was looking for the intuitions, base model accuracy is very low in this analysis. as you also mentioned,  i will to do some more feature engineering, will see if accuracy improves..  Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewBrēza, yes Andrew, manually I have to go, Thanks!